# C linked list: Segmentation fault on Windows, works on Mac

Tags: c, xcode, list, linked-list, segmentation-fault

I'm trying to go through a linked list in C.

A list item is defined as

```
struct list_element {
  struct list_element *next;
  int value;
};
```

The list head is defined as

```
struct list_head {
  struct list_element *front;
  struct list_element *end;
};
```

and I'm trying to print the items like this

```
void printList(struct list_head* head) {
    if(head == NULL|| head->front == NULL) {
        printf("List is empty \n");
        return 0;
    }

    struct list_element* elm = head-> front;
    int numberOfElements = 0;

    while(elm != NULL) {
        printf("%i", elm -> value);
        printf(" ");
        elm = elm -> next;
    }
    printf("\n");
}
```

This works perfect on my Mac in XCode and on https://ideone.com, but on Windows and http://codepad.org it results in "Segmentation fault". It seems like

```
while(elm != NULL) {
    printf("%i", elm -> value);
    printf(" ");
    elm = elm -> next;
}
```

causes some issues. It seems like elm doesn't point to NULL for the last item, even though it should.

I'm adding items like this

```
struct list_element* list_push(struct list_head* head) {

    //List head is null
    if(!head) {
        return NULL;
    }

    //Initialize list element

    struct list_element* elm = malloc(sizeof(struct list_element));

    if(elm == NULL) {
        //Couldn't alloc memory
        return NULL;
    }

    if(head->front) {
        head->front = elm;
        head->end = elm;
    } else {
        //List head is not null, set next elm to point to current elm
        elm -> next = head -> front;
        head->front = elm;

    }

    return elm;
}
```

And I'm seriously confused why the same code would work in some places but not in others. (It works on IDEone and XCode, it doesn't work on Codepad and Code::blocks on Windows with the same code)

[Example on IDEone](https://ideone.com/kEhPBV)
[Example on Codepad](http://codepad.org/r1Xn6mjZ)

Comment: Debugging in XCode doesn't show any errors and valgrind neither. But running the compiled binary results in Segmentation fault

Comment: Generally if your program segfault on one computer and seems to "work" on another, then it exhibits "undefined behaviour". Google "undefined behaviour C" to learn more.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to initialize `ele->next` with `NULL` for the first element of list, Otherwise you access to uninitialized memory in `elm = elm->next` for the last element of list. Apart from this you have to change `if(head->front)` to `if ( head->front == NULL )`. Adapt your code like this:

```
struct list_element* list_push(struct list_head* head) {

    if ( head == NULL )
        return NULL;

    struct list_element* elm = malloc(sizeof(struct list_element));
    if ( elm == NULL)
        return NULL;

    if ( head->front == NULL)  // <--------------
    {
        elm->next = NULL;     // <---------------
        head->front = elm;
        head->end = elm;
    }
    else
    {    
        elm->next   = head->front;
        head->front = elm;
    }
    return elm;
}
```

Make sure you initialized `head->front` an `head->end` with `NULL`.

Comment: Thanks, it seems like the issue was the fact that I forgot to initialize head->front and head->end with NULL.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that `malloc` is not zeroing the memory allocated to it for you. You can either set the `next` pointer to `NULL` manually, or you can use `calloc` to allocate the memory, which will zero it for you. The reason it works in some environments and not others is that either it's hitting memory that was already written with zeros in some cases, or that some operating systems will zero out the memory for you for security reasons.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the information. I wasn't aware of this fact.

Comment: `calloc` will clear all bits of the area, which is not necessarily the same as a _null pointer_ (or `0.0`, btw.). Better is to explicitly set the pointers.